# Replace underscore character with printable character for all file name using loop

Tags: shell-script

Currently I'm learning scripting, so trying to write some random script. Today I written a script which will take a file type as arument and replace space with underscore in name of all current directory file of this type. I written a code for this taking help from this site. That is given below:

```
#!/bin/bash

fileFormat="$1"

for file in *\ *."$fileFormat"
do
    mv "$file" "${file// /_}";
done
```

Now I want to replace all underscore character to any alphabet or digit (Let it be 'a'). So that there is no underscore in the file name. How will I do that? I tried but failed... :(

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

The script I wrote here runs without any problem. What I want now I tried that by googling. I don't know what to read in ***destination*** of mv command to get my expected result. That is what I asking for.

Comment: Do you want to replace it with [a null-character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character)? (If even possible, that may get you in trouble trying to use the files afterwards.) Or remove it altogether?

Comment: Ok, got it. What about if I want to underscore character with a numerical digit? or with an alphabet? @Arjan

Comment: What have you actually tried and what was the result of said experiment? Did you get any error messages or similar that might be helpful?

Comment: The script I wrote here runs without any problem. What I want now I tried that by googling. I don't know what to read in destination of mv command to get my expected result. That is what I asking for.